# How do i modify a log format with Simple Formatter?

Tags: java, logging, formatter, java.util.logging

I've tried adding this line into logging.properties, but the output doesn't change

`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format='%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n'`

I also tried System.setProperty, but it still doesn't work, what am i doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LoggerFormat
{
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerFormat.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%1$tF %1$tT %4$s %2$s %1$tL");
    SimpleFormatter sf = new SimpleFormatter();
    System.out.println("-- main method starts --");
    logger.info("in LoggerFormat");
    logger.warning("a test warning");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of things can go wrong here.  First make sure you are running a version of Java (7 b138) or later that has fix for [JDK-6381464 : SimpleFormatter should use one single line format](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6381464).

One thing that is not explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) is that quotes are only needed on the pattern if you are [setting the pattern via the command line](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7152819) and the pattern contains a whitespace character.

So if you are setting the format in the logging.properties then drop the quotes:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n
```

If you are setting the format as a system property then you have to set it on launch:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n"
```

Next thing you want to do is use a test program to verify that your pattern compiles.  If the pattern syntax is wrong the SimpleFormatter will fall back to the default pattern.  Here is an example test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String format = "%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n";
    final String key = "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format";
    test(format);
    test(System.getProperty(key, format));
    test(LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty(key));
    test(new SimpleFormatter());
}

private static void test(Formatter f) {
    LogRecord record = newLogRecord();
    System.out.println(f.format(record));
}

private static LogRecord newLogRecord() {
    LogRecord r = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Message");
    r.setSourceClassName("sourceClassName");
    r.setSourceMethodName("sourceMethodName");
    r.setLoggerName("loggerName");
    r.setThrown(new Throwable("thrown"));
    return r;
}

private static void test(String format) {
    if (format != null) {
        LogRecord record = newLogRecord();
        Throwable t = record.getThrown();
        System.out.println(String.format(format,
                new java.util.Date(record.getMillis()),
                record.getSourceClassName(),
                record.getLoggerName(),
                record.getLevel().getLocalizedName(),
                record.getMessage(),
                t != null ? t.toString() : ""));
        //TODO: Place printStackTrace into a string.
    } else {
        System.out.println("Format is null.");
    }
}
```

Finally, the format can only be set one time on startup.  As soon as the SimpleFormatter is loaded that pattern is used for the life of the class.  Using `System.setProperty` will only work if you set the pattern before logging starts so don't depend on that route ever working in a complex program.